# Cocoa Bindings with Core Data not updating all columns

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I'm having this strange issue where I have an NSArrayController bound to a managedObjectContext and using the array controller to populate an NSTableView. I can create an object and insert it and it will add the new object and update one of the columns bound to the controller but not the others! I know the fields are being set and bindings are working correctly (perhaps) because if I close the app and restart the app everything is correctly populated.

I'm not sure what I'm missing! How can I debug the bindings? From what I've found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002320-SW6
it basically just says could be your controller or key value coding compliance.

Here is the code creating the entity:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[BugManager shared] managedObjectContext];
NSError* error;
Bug* newBug = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Bug" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newBug setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:data];
[context save:&error];
```

I have verified that all the fields are set correctly and saved. I also tried to set the values explicitly to see if it was a key value observing issue to no avail.

This is the column that is updating correctly:

[image]

Here is the one that isn't updating correctly:

[image]

And the array controller:

[image]

I can rearrange the table columns and it still only updates one, the target field (the one it was updating previously). I just want the table to update all the columns correctly but it is being more difficult than expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours and hours of slamming my head into the wall I traced the problem to not how the binding was set up (as it was correct) but actually how my data was being created. In the form that I was using to populate the object I had a text field and a text view. The text field was working correctly but the text view wasn't. When I switched to try a text field for both it worked as well. Or if I hard coded a string literal the bindings updated correctly. The fix for me was to create an explicit `NSString*` from the text view. If you ask for it's string it was giving me back an `NSBigMutableString` for some reason setting the core data field with this didn't fire the notification.

So I did this:

```
NSString* description = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[self descriptionField] textStorage] string]];
```

I then use that string value for my entity and everything works as it should.